# How to categorise data structures in a class c++

Tags: c++

I want to be able to categorise data structures of a class.
Essentially what im asking is, is there a functionality similar to namespaces but for classes?

e.g

```
class Person{
public:
//attributes

//capabilities

};
```

Comment: What exactly would this "category" do? Aren't code comments sufficient?

Comment: If you have so many that you need categorization, the class may be too bloated. Refactoring into smaller classes with more well-defined responsibility may be prudent.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `structs` or `class` to organize data? Like this:

```
class Person{
  public:
  struct attr
  {

  } attributes;

  struct cap
  {

  } capabilities;    

};
```

Just remember that member functions of `struct attr` does not know of the object `capabilities` (Only indirectly, when given a pointer/reference to `capabilities`). And in the same way, `struct cap` cannot directly access `attributes`